# Is this a good approach for a "pImpl"-based class hierarchy in C++?

Tags: design, c++, c++11

I have a class hierarchy for which I would like to separate the interface from the implementation. My solution is to have two hierarchies: a handle class hierarchy for the interface and a non-public class hierarchy for the implementation. The base handle class has a pointer-to-implementation which the derived handle classes cast to a pointer of the derived type (see function `getPimpl()`).

Here's a sketch of my solution for a base class with two derived classes. Is there a better solution?

**File "Base.h":**

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
protected:
    class Impl;
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl;
    Base(Impl* pImpl) : pImpl{pImpl} {};
    ...
};

class Derived_1 final : public Base {
protected:
    class Impl;
    inline Derived_1* getPimpl() const noexcept {
        return reinterpret_cast<Impl*>(pImpl.get());
    }
public:
    Derived_1(...);
    void func_1(...) const;
    ...
};

class Derived_2 final : public Base {
protected:
    class Impl;
    inline Derived_2* getPimpl() const noexcept {
        return reinterpret_cast<Impl*>(pImpl.get());
    }
public:
    Derived_2(...);
    void func_2(...) const;
    ...
};
```

**File "Base.cpp":**

```
class Base::Impl {
public:
    Impl(...) {...}
    ...
};

class Derived_1::Impl final : public Base::Impl {
public:
    Impl(...) : Base::Impl(...) {...}
    void func_1(...) {...}
    ...
};

class Derived_2::Impl final : public Base::Impl {
public:
    Impl(...) : Base::Impl(...) {...}
    void func_2(...) {...}
    ...
};

Derived_1::Derived_1(...) : Base(new Derived_1::Impl(...)) {...}
Derived_1::func_1(...) const { getPimpl()->func_1(...); }

Derived_2::Derived_2(...) : Base(new Derived_2::Impl(...)) {...}
Derived_2::func_2(...) const { getPimpl()->func_2(...); }
```

Comment: Which of these classes will be visible from the outside of the library/component? If only `Base`, a normal abstract base class ("interface") and concrete implementations without pimpl might be enough.

Comment: @D.Jurcau The base and derived classes will all be publicly visible. Obviously, the implementation classes will not.

Comment: Why downcast? Base class is at strange position here, it can be replaced with a shared pointer with improved typeasafety and less code.

Comment: @Basilevs I don't understand. The public base class uses the pimpl idiom  to hide the implementation. I don't see how replacing it with a shared pointer can maintain the class hierarchy without casting or duplicating the pointer. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: I propose to duplicate pointer, instead of replicating downcast.

Comment: You may consider [bridge pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge)

Comment: Do the impl classes need to follow the same hierarchy? They often dont need to.

Comment: @Teimpz The domain being modeled lends itself to an implementation hierarchy -- both in the implementation and in the handle classes.

Comment: @QQ I don't think the bridge pattern applies. The handle and implementation hierarchies aren't orthogonal and the pimpl idiom already decouples them.

Comment: Seems like I was 2 months late with my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a poor strategy to make `Derived_1::Impl` derive from `Base::Impl`.

The main purpose of using the Pimpl idiom is to hide the implementation details of a class. By letting `Derived_1::Impl` derive from `Base::Impl`, you've defeated that purpose. Now, not only does the implementation of `Base` depend on `Base::Impl`, the implementation of `Derived_1` also depends on `Base::Impl`.

> Is there a better solution?

That depends on what trade-offs are acceptable to you.

**Solution 1**

Make `Impl` classes totally independent. This will imply that there will be two pointers to `Impl` classes -- one in `Base` and another one in `Derived_N`.

```
class Base {

   protected:
      Base() : pImpl{new Impl()} {}

   private:
      // It's own Impl class and pointer.
      class Impl { };
      std::shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl;

};

class Derived_1 final : public Base {
   public:
      Derived_1() : Base(), pImpl{new Impl()} {}
      void func_1() const;
   private:
      // It's own Impl class and pointer.
      class Impl { };
      std::shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl;
};
```

**Solution 2**

Expose the classes only as handles. Don't expose the class definitions and implementations at all.

Public header file:

```
struct Handle {unsigned long id;};
struct Derived1_tag {};
struct Derived2_tag {};

Handle constructObject(Derived1_tag tag);
Handle constructObject(Derived2_tag tag);

void deleteObject(Handle h);

void fun(Handle h, Derived1_tag tag);
void bar(Handle h, Derived2_tag tag);
```

Here's quick implementation

```
#include <map>

class Base
{
   public:
      virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
};

namespace Base_Impl
{
   struct CompareHandle
   {
      bool operator()(Handle h1, Handle h2) const
      {
         return (h1.id < h2.id);
      }
   };

   using ObjectMap = std::map<Handle, Base*, CompareHandle>;

   ObjectMap& getObjectMap()
   {
      static ObjectMap theMap;
      return theMap;
   }

   unsigned long getNextID()
   {
      static unsigned id = 0;
      return ++id;
   }

   Handle getHandle(Base* obj)
   {
      auto id = getNextID();
      Handle h{id};
      getObjectMap()[h] = obj;
      return h;
   }

   Base* getObject(Handle h)
   {
      return getObjectMap()[h];
   }

   template <typename Der>
      Der* getObject(Handle h)
      {
         return dynamic_cast<Der*>(getObject(h));
      }
};

using namespace Base_Impl;

Handle constructObject(Derived1_tag tag)
{
   // Construct an object of type Derived1
   Derived1* obj = new Derived1;

   // Get a handle to the object and return it.
   return getHandle(obj);
}

Handle constructObject(Derived2_tag tag)
{
   // Construct an object of type Derived2
   Derived2* obj = new Derived2;

   // Get a handle to the object and return it.
   return getHandle(obj);
}

void deleteObject(Handle h)
{
   // Get a pointer to Base given the Handle.
   //
   Base* obj = getObject(h);

   // Remove it from the map.
   // Delete the object.
   if ( obj != nullptr )
   {
      getObjectMap().erase(h);
      delete obj;
   }
}

void fun(Handle h, Derived1_tag tag)
{
   // Get a pointer to Derived1 given the Handle.
   Derived1* obj = getObject<Derived1>(h);
   if ( obj == nullptr )
   {
      // Problem.
      // Decide how to deal with it.

      return;
   }

   // Use obj
}

void bar(Handle h, Derived2_tag tag)
{
   Derived2* obj = getObject<Derived2>(h);
   if ( obj == nullptr )
   {
      // Problem.
      // Decide how to deal with it.

      return;
   }

   // Use obj
}
```

**Pros and Cons**

With the first approach, you can construct `Derived` classes in the stack. With the second approach, that is not an option.

With the first approach, you incur the cost of two dynamic allocations and deallocations for constructing and destructing a `Derived` in the stack. If you construct and destruct a `Derived` object from the heap you, incur the cost of one more allocation and deallocation. With the second approach, you only incur the cost of one dynamic allocation and one deallocation for every object.

With the first approach, you get have the ability to use `virtual` member function is `Base`. With the second approach, that is not an option.

**My suggestion**

I would go with the first solution so I can use the class hierarchy and `virtual` member functions in `Base` even though it is a little bit more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement I can see here is to let the concrete classes define the implementation field. If the abstract base classes need it, they can define an abstract property that is easy to implement in the concrete classes:

#### Base.h

```
class Base {
protected:
    class Impl;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Impl> getImpl() =0;
    ...
};

class Derived_1 final : public Base {
protected:
    class Impl1;
    std::shared_ptr<Impl1> pImpl
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Base::Impl> getImpl();
public:
    Derived_1(...);
    void func_1(...) const;
    ...
};
```

#### Base.cpp

```
class Base::Impl {
public:
    Impl(...) {...}
    ...
};

class Derived_1::Impl1 final : public Base::Impl {
public:
    Impl(...) : Base::Impl(...) {...}
    void func_1(...) {...}
    ...
};

std::shared_ptr<Base::Impl> Derived_1::getImpl() { return pPimpl; }
Derived_1::Derived_1(...) : pPimpl(std::make_shared<Impl1>(...)) {...}
void Derived_1::func_1(...) const { pPimpl->func_1(...); }
```

This seems to be safer to me. If you have a big tree, you can also introduce `virtual std::shared_ptr<Impl1> getImpl1() =0` in the middle of the tree.